# Only show latest date from duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the latest odds just before kick off for football games using Betfair's historical data.  My database looks as follows:

[Current DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t788f.png)

Now Betfair's historical data records the odds many times a day and therefore has lots of duplicate data.  I have so far managed to only get all the odds for the selected Correct Score markets before kickoff.

As you can see there are duplicate records but I want to be able to only get the latest (max) time for each of the Correct Scores.  I have highlighted the rows that I want the final query to only output.

My SQL statement is as follows:

```
SELECT "SCHEDULED_OFF", "FULL_DESCRIPTION", "EVENT", 
   "SELECTION_ID", "SELECTION", "ODDS", "WIN_FLAG", "LATEST_TAKEN"
FROM "bfinf_other_161017to161023_161026123339"
WHERE "FULL_DESCRIPTION" LIKE 'English Soccer/English Premier League%' 
    AND "EVENT" = "Correct Score" 
    AND "LATEST_TAKEN" < "SCHEDULED_OFF"
ORDER BY "FULL_DESCRIPTION" ASC, "SELECTION" ASC, "LATEST_TAKEN" DESC
```

I've tried to GROUP BY "FULL_DESCRIPTION" and "SELECTION" but nothing seems to be happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Michael

Comment: Check multiple answers, not just the accepted one.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Very odd table name, `bfinf_other_161017to161023_161026123339`. Do you have different tables for different dates? How come?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter based on in clause  and subselect with max `LATEST_TAKEN` group by `SELECTION_ID`

```
SELECT `SCHEDULED_OFF`, `FULL_DESCRIPTION`, `EVENT`, `SELECTION_ID`, `SELECTION`, `ODDS`, `WIN_FLAG`, `LATEST_TAKEN`
FROM `bfinf_other_161017to161023_161026123339`
WHERE `FULL_DESCRIPTION` LIKE 'English Soccer/English Premier League%' 
AND `EVENT` = `Correct Score` 
AND `LATEST_TAKEN` IN  ( select MAX(LATEST_TAKEN`  
                       from `bfinf_other_161017to161023_161026123339` 
                       group by `SELECTION_ID`)
ORDER BY `FULL_DESCRIPTION` ASC, `SELECTION` ASC, `LATEST_TAKEN` DESC
```

Don't use double quote  (if you need use backticks)

Answer (score 0):

Add a Where clause predicate that restricts output to the row with the latest datetime. Use subquery to determine the latest datetime for each selection.

```
SELECT "SCHEDULED_OFF", "FULL_DESCRIPTION", "EVENT", 
    "SELECTION_ID", "SELECTION", "ODDS", "WIN_FLAG", "LATEST_TAKEN"
FROM "bfinf_other_161017to161023_161026123339" a
WHERE "FULL_DESCRIPTION" LIKE 'English Soccer/English Premier League%' 
   AND "EVENT" = "Correct Score" 
   AND "LATEST_TAKEN" < "SCHEDULED_OFF"
   and LATEST_TAKEN = 
      (Select Max(LATEST_TAKEN) 
       From bfinf_other_161017to161023_161026123339
       Where Selection_Id = a.Selection_Id)
ORDER BY "FULL_DESCRIPTION" ASC, "SELECTION" ASC, "LATEST_TAKEN" DESC
```